# How to design a nav-tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a nav-tabs like arrow shape.

can anyone tell me that which css property will be applicable to get this shape.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">network</a></li>
   <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">adress</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">AAA</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="b">BBB</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="c">CCC</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="d">DDD</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vtwoxyb/1/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ last example on the page...

Comment: Here is another link to help you: https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Comment: @sinisake thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [breadcrumbs](https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#breadcrumb .icon {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
}
#breadcrumb li a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  background: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 23px;
}
#breadcrumb li:nth-child(even) a {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
#breadcrumb li:nth-child(even) a:before {
  border-color: #2980b9;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#breadcrumb li:nth-child(even) a:after {
  border-left-color: #2980b9;
}
#breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
#breadcrumb li:first-child a:before {
  border: none;
}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a:after {
  border: none;
}
#breadcrumb li a:before, #breadcrumb li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 0 solid #3498db;
  border-width: 20px 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#breadcrumb li a:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#breadcrumb li a:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #3498db;
}
#breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
#breadcrumb li a:hover:before {
  border-color: #1abc9c;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #1abc9c;
}
#breadcrumb li a:active {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
#breadcrumb li a:active:before {
  border-color: #16a085;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#breadcrumb li a:active:after {
  border-left-color: #16a085;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul id="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">network</a></li>
   <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab">adress</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @krish you can add some padding.